# How to use Google translate Api in my android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an android app for language translation in real time...I used recognizer intent to get voice input from user after which it gives me a list of options of what the user spoke.Now I want to translate it another language using google translate api but I don't know how to use it. Code for what I have done till now is.Also if you can tell me how it can be done that instead of giving me options of what I spoke , it selects one on its own and then use google translate api on that....

```
package com.example.testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Voice extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    ListView lv;
    static final int check=1111;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.voice);
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bVoice);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak Up");
        startActivityForResult(i, check);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode == check && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            ArrayList<String> results=data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
```

Comment: what issue/error you are getting currently ?

Comment: no issues are there...I want to know how to use google translate api to translate this input from user.....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is the documentation for https://developers.google.com/translate/

Also, refer to [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-api-translate-java/) demo project on the same

Bing also provides a [translation API](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx)

Check [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/10/androidtranslate-using-google-translate.html) Google translation API example .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you see this question why it isn't working...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870060/bing-translate-api-not-working

Comment: Both Google and Bingo have quotes?

Comment: It is not a free service :-)