# bing translate api not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My app crashes as soon as this activity starts. It doesn't crash on clicking the button. The code is as follows

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.memetix.mst.language.Language;
import com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate;

public class TranslateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText etInput;
    EditText etOutput;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_translate);
        Translate.setClientId("hidden");
        Translate.setClientSecret("hidden");
        Button Trans = (Button)findViewById(R.id.translate);
        Trans.setOnClickListener(this);
        etInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
        etOutput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        //get the text entered      
                String In =etInput.getText().toString();
                //String Out;
                try {
                    String Out = Translate.execute(In, Language.AUTO_DETECT, Language.FRENCH);
                etInput.setText(Out);
                etOutput.setText(Out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
}
```

ClientId and Client Secret are string,so I placed them in between " "...Is that right....

Logcat is as follows:

```
04-04 14:05:45.250: D/dalvikvm(1002): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 5% free 2888K/3040K, paused 242ms, total 263ms
04-04 14:05:45.260: I/dalvikvm-heap(1002): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.726MB for 1920016-byte allocation
04-04 14:05:45.360: D/dalvikvm(1002): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 4760K/4916K, paused 91ms, total 91ms
04-04 14:05:47.860: E/MediaPlayer(1002): Should have subtitle controller already set
04-04 14:05:48.610: D/gralloc_goldfish(1002): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-04 14:05:49.500: D/dalvikvm(1002): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12K, 2% free 4904K/4996K, paused 35ms, total 36ms
04-04 14:05:50.330: I/Choreographer(1002): Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-04 14:05:55.970: D/dalvikvm(1002): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 31K, 2% free 5551K/5664K, paused 32ms, total 42ms
04-04 14:05:56.040: D/dalvikvm(1002): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1920K, 32% free 4442K/6480K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
04-04 14:05:56.070: I/Choreographer(1002): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-04 14:05:57.330: I/Choreographer(1002): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-04 14:05:59.130: W/dalvikvm(1002): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1592 (AUTO_DETECT) in Lcom/memetix/mst/language/Language;
04-04 14:05:59.140: D/dalvikvm(1002): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000a

04-04 14:05:59.140: I/dalvikvm(1002): Could not find method com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate.setClientId, referenced from method com.example.testing.TranslateActivity.onCreate
04-04 14:05:59.140: W/dalvikvm(1002): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5277: Lcom/memetix/mst/translate/Translate;.setClientId (Ljava/lang/String;)V
04-04 14:05:59.140: D/dalvikvm(1002): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000b
04-04 14:05:59.250: I/Choreographer(1002): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-04 14:05:59.430: D/dalvikvm(1002): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1363K, 44% free 3640K/6480K, paused 80ms, total 84ms
04-04 14:05:59.890: D/AndroidRuntime(1002): Shutting down VM
04-04 14:05:59.890: W/dalvikvm(1002): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ad1b90)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002): Process: com.example.testing, PID: 1002
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at com.example.testing.TranslateActivity.onCreate(TranslateActivity.java:21)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-04 14:05:59.930: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 14:06:06.350: I/Process(1002): Sending signal. PID: 1002 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Is com.memetix.mst.translate.Translate on your classpath?

Comment: nope it isn't...how to make it?

Comment: It is in dexedlibs inside  bin...I haven't got solution yet

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the jar file to your project?

You need to download the jar file and add it to your class path.

Follow these steps:

1. Download the jar file to a directory: https://code.google.com/p/microsoft-translator-java-api/downloads/list
2. In eclipse right click on your libs folder and go to Import -> General -> File System, then browse to the directory in which the jar file was downloaded and click Ok. then select from the jar file from the window in eclipse and click finish to add the jar to your project
3. Right click on your project and go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path, then click the Libraries tab and add jar's. Navigate to the jar file in your libs folder and click done/finish/ok.