# Is there any library for app translation?

Tags: android

Is there a lib which translates the app on regular/not rooted devices?
Something like Google Chrome has for pages not in my language.

Comment: Not sure if there are libraries, I guess you can use Google Translate API.

Comment: you shouldn't ask to find you a library here (yes, that is not my own idea, that's the So rules).

Answer (score 0):

Use google translater api [refer](https://cloud.google.com/translate/)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829657/how-to-use-google-translate-api-in-my-android-app).Get Local Language get translate into that language using this api

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what do you want, but you can set custom language as described below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/7996129

Comment: I want to have only english resources in the app, which will be translated into user's device language.

Comment: you can't just answer with a link to another answer.