# Import Google Translation API to Android Studio

Tags: android, rest, google-translate

I´ve registered for Google Cloud Services and activated the Google Cloud Translation API. Now I want to start an Android Studio Project, using this API. In the documentation they refer to Import the following librarys:

```
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translate.TranslateOption;
import com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateOptions;
import com.google.cloud.translate.Translation;
```

How to get these librarys for Java/Android Studio?

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries

On this page under 'Installing the client library' one can not find something for Java.

So how to use this API in Android Studio?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829657/how-to-use-google-translate-api-in-my-android-app

Comment: compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0'  put this in your app gradle and sync project

Comment: thank you Sorathiya. When I try to compile my Project now I´m getting an annotation processor Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
    - auto-value-1.2.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2) any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0'
}
```

into my build.gradle solved the problem.