# String Translation from API call

Tags: java, android, json, android-library, okhttp

I have a found a free API to get some data I need for my app. The thing is the values that I get are in English.

I wanted to know if there is some way to translate this strings in my language before showing them to the users.

Comment: You can try Google or Microsoft's translate API https://stackoverflow.com/a/22829786/1536286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate text but it will require another API call. Not only that, but you will have to create an appropriate request object and parse a response object from your chosen API.

You have various API providers to choose from, the top Google hits being:

1. Google: https://cloud.google.com/translate/
2. Yandex: https://tech.yandex.com/translate/

But beware! Machine translation is patchy at best. The likelihood of getting odd sounding or outright wrong results, particularly for anything other than simple text, is very high.

Comment: are these for free ?

Comment: Yes, you just need to register to obtain an API key

Comment: i used Yandex , great answer

Comment: @StavroXhardha,  Here's the pricing details: yandex: https://translate.yandex.com/developers/offer/prices and google: https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing.