# How can I translate English text to Japanese text programmatically?

Tags: android

I have a edit text that can input English words/sentence and I want it to convert to Japanese text. Is there any API I can use to achieve this?

For Example:

I type: Hello

The expected output in my Textview should be: こんにちは

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829657/how-to-use-google-translate-api-in-my-android-app

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert this into Android:[py-googletrans](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it run locally then you can have a file (csv txt with the words) and read them or connect to a server with database of words